# JavaFX & FXML. Nested lists in combobox

Tags: javafx, combobox, fxml, scenebuilder

I am making an app and need to create a combobox with nested lists. 
Like you have some options when you click on the combobox, but you can also click on them to get more options.

I am trying to make it with SceneBuilder and have no clue how to make it work.

Comment: Have you done anything yet to try and make what you are trying to make? Posting your code would be helpful for us in determining what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: It almost sounds like you are trying to build a menu system with submenus within it?